# how to get log info when i run cmd.start(xx.exe)

Tags: windows, go, cmd, loginfo

source code is:

```golang
//this code run in parent process
cmd:=exec.Command("cmd","/c","./child.exe")
if e:=cmd.Start();e!=nil{
  //todo handle error
}
//child.exe handle task maybe long time
os.Exit() //notice!!! parent process will kill itself because test.exe will rm parent process
```

My problem is test.exe have anything log info in cmd.

Answer (score 0):

More or less like this:

```
cmd := exec.Command("cmd", "/c", "./child.exe")
out := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
cmd.Stdout = out
if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {

}
fmt.Println(out.String())
```

Comment: this code run in parent and will kill itself after run

```golang
cmd.Run()
```

actually ,child process run task

1. sleep 3 secondes(make sure parent process has killed)
2. os.Remove(./parent.exe)
3. download some message